# Facebook's comments plug-in problem with data-width

Tags: facebook, width, comments

I try to make Facebook comments box with [Facebook's plugin maker](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/). But I can't change the "data-width" wider like 550px.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known bug in Facebook, as you can see here if you have a Facebook account: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/173395380238318

The Facebook developers are working on it. This is what worked for me:

```
change data-width='100%' to width='100%'
```

Comment: This is not an open link accessible without a Facebook account. Better is to write what you discovered into your answer (citation) and say some words about it to make it clear what is exactly wrong.

Comment: I've formatted your answer, hope this is much clearer now.

Comment: Changing the data-width to width actually fixed the issue. Do not forget to change it back when developpers will have completed the fix.

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar problem, whereas previously this was working fine. I think this may be a bug with Facebook's Comment Plugin.